# jQuery resize and position current browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, location

How can I set height, width and set the position of the current browser window in the `document.ready()` function of jQuery ?

Comment: you mean relative to the user's screen?

Comment: Be aware that all modern browsers will greatly restrict your ability to control those things, if they let you control any of them at all.

Comment: I would like to get jQuery functions rather than javascript functions

Answer (score 4):

There supposed to be two javascript functions to resize and move the browser window:

```
window.resizeTo(width, height);
window.moveTo(x, y);
```

These functions are not supported by Chrome and Opera, and other browsers might experience certain security restrictions as well.

If you want to pop a new window with a certain size, check out the [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) of `window.open()`. Your interface should also not rely on it entirely, for example you won't be able to do it on mobile browsers.

When thinking about if something is possible or not it's always a good start to think about ways to abuse it. Would you want windows on your screen to jump around every 100 milliseconds,  just because some website wants to do that? Probably that's why it's unsupported or limited these days.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But at the start of the application, it comes to a normal sized window, then it resize to the width and height. So user can see the things whats going on. How can I avoid this.