# Assign element width to window width after window rendered

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get an html element's width like so:

```
var elementWidth = document.getElementById("myElement").style.width;
```

Then I want to assign this to the current window which is a popup created using:

```
window.open("myUrl","myName","width=200,height=200");
```

How would I go about doing that? Any pointers coz the windows cant be assign width & height values like elements.

Comment: So, in other words, you want to change the size of a window that is already open?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery resize and position current browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125796/jquery-resize-and-position-current-browser-window)

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon Yes that is correct, is this possible?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon That question answered my question, thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by doing:

```
var elemWidth = document.getElementById("myElem").style.width;
var elemHeight = document.getElementById("myElem").style.height;
window.resizeTo(elemWidth,elemHeight);
```